# man nmap goes gibberish after nmap upgraded by brew

Tags: macos, nmap, manpage

After executing `brew upgrade` to upgrade my package on macOS, the **nmap** is upgraded to the latest version(7.70), there appeared a failed link to **ncat**, with some possible conflict files related to **man** listed, then I followed the advice provided by homebrew, executed the following commands:

```
rm '/usr/local/bin/ncat'
brew link --overwrite nmap
brew link --overwrite --dry-run nmap
```

It seemed that all the thing went well, but when I executed `man nmap`, the appeared page was a mess of codes, it went gibberish like this:

[Errors of installation of **nmap**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8Yur.png)

[A mess of codes in manpage for **nmap** part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0wGe.png)

[A mess of codes in manpage for **nmap** part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aJsC.jpg)

I had tried reinstall the nmap but it didn’t work.
So, can anyone tell me how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have self-solved my problem. According to the errors in the pictures provided by the question, there are some conflict files in `/usr/local/share/man/`, so just delete the following files that can solve the problem.
The files are:

```
/usr/local/share/man/de/man1/nmap.1
/usr/local/share/man/es/man1/nmap.1
/usr/local/share/man/fr/man1/nmap.1
/usr/local/share/man/hr/man1/nmap.1
/usr/local/share/man/hu/man1/nmap.1
/usr/local/share/man/it/man1/nmap.1
/usr/local/share/man/ja/man1/nmap.1
/usr/local/share/man/man1/ncat.1
/usr/local/share/man/man1/ndiff.1
/usr/local/share/man/man1/nmap.1
/usr/local/share/man/man1/nping.1
/usr/local/share/man/pl/man1/nmap.1
/usr/local/share/man/pt_BR/man1/nmap.1
/usr/local/share/man/pt_PT/man1/nmap.1
/usr/local/share/man/ro/man1/nmap.1
/usr/local/share/man/ru/man1/nmap.1
/usr/local/share/man/sk/man1/nmap.1
/usr/local/share/man/zh/man1/nmap.1
```

After deleting these **nmap.1**, both the empty directory can also be deleted to make the *man* directory clean.